# AES encrypt in PHP 7.1 and in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, cryptography

We used to be able to use the mcrypt function to en/decrypt data. This was perfect because mysql and PHP shared the same principle which made encryption very flexible for us. You could pick where to en/decrypt and therefore offload some tasks to application nodes or DB as you wanted.

But as of PHP 7.1 mcrypt was deprecated which makes sharing encryption impossible again.

Is there a way to still use the mcrypt function on both systems. Or better, is there a new encryption that works the same on PHP and mysql.

If not, what is the best way to still put encrypted user data in your DB whilst still be able to search through it.

Comment: would you explain what's in common between php and mysql in mcrypt encryption ?

Comment: here are some general considerations for encrypting databases you may want to take into account. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/is-it-generally-a-bad-idea-to-encrypt-database-fields

Comment: [Remi (PHP contributor) has some suggestions](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding bugs dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Thank you all for these comments. I have read the security questions and can easily say that those are not a threat at the moment seeing the programming is fine for now. We are however bound by law to obscure user data in our databases. So normally we encrypt the data (AES) in Laravel and push it to mysql. But you also need to be able to search through that data (search field) sometimes. This is where mysql and mcrypt overlap. That being said, I'm aware of mysql logs that contain crypto keys and such, but that is not in the scope of this question and need not be the issue for now.

Comment: Also, it's good that they took away mcrypt. I'm just looking for an alternative to this problem.